# Excel VBA print button with user prompt

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a Print button in Excel with a specific range.
The columns never change, but the row does.

My goal is that the user can click on the PrintButton. After that a prompt asks for the row he want's to use.

Here's what I got so far but I'm stuck =/

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = InputBox("Please enter the row you're working on.", "Enter Row", "")

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range("N" & myValue, "O" & myValue)
ActiveSheet.PrintOut
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = False


End Sub
```

Any hint how to proceed?

Thanks and have a great day! =)

Edit:
After a little research I came up with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("HARDWARE-INVENTORY").Select
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = InputBox("Please enter the row you're working on.", "Enter Row", "")

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Range("N" & myValue & ":O" & myValue)
myRange.PrintOut


End Sub
```

Now I just have to figure out how to exclude the freezed header-row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this which uses `Application.InputBox` to get the user to select a range

`8` for the last argument tells Excel the user should return a range

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select row", "Enter Row", ActiveCell.EntireRow.Address, , , , , 8)
rng1.PrintOut
```

*longer version with error handling*

```
Sub A2()
Dim rng1 As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Select row", "Enter Row", ActiveCell.EntireRow.Address, , , , , 8)
On erorr GoTo 0

'no range
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If rng1.Rows.Count = 1 Then
    rng1.PrintOut
Else
    MsgBox "too many rows", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly!
I edited my question before I saw your reply.

It seems that I didn't define my range as a range.
Do you know how to exclude the freezed header from the printout?